# Validation on custom button and Visualforce content

Tags: visualforce

Trying to work out of something is possible.

I have a managed package installed that has a custom button which publishes the content source which is a visualforce page when clicked. I want to create a new custom button that publishes the same Visualforce page after a validation is performed on the record to make sure all the required fields. If all of them are complete then show the visualforce page, if not push them back to record showing an error message asking them to complete the fields.

Does this sound doable and how would I go about this?

Many thanks

Comment: Is that button customizable? For ex: Docusign buttons are customizable and you can play around on what parameters are passed to their URL..